# Is griefing by mobs in Minecraft really random?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When a creeper settled on the only part of rail in miles that had powered rails, I shrugged it off. When two creepers dropped on me from above without giving me a second of chance, just as I was passing over a lake of fire, I thought "bad luck". But when I ran naked at night, after a respawn, to a shelter with iron door, chased by a crowd of mobs, only to find the one specific block with the door button removed by an enderman, I began suspecting there's more to it than "hide in random dark place", "move blocks at random" etc.

Is there a specific code in Minecraft, responsible for mobs trying to damage critical infrastructure on purpose? e.g. an enderman preferring that one block with a button on it versus 300 other blocks of the house?

Comment: So: are mobs programmed to troll players? Interesting ...

Comment: Nope, they are truly random. If you know any Java, you can verify this fact for yourself by downloading the Minecraft Coder Pack

Comment: @Ruirize Maybe the Endermen removed the code block that showed their true motivations.

Comment: Are you running any mods? A mod that looks normal enough might do something like this. Just a thought

Comment: @pattyd: No, vanilla. (and yes, I was afk until now.)

Comment: I loled at the Enderman removing your button block. Thats just hilarious. You do know the Enderman can only remove certain blocks nowadays? Just build your house out of Enderman-proof blocks.

Comment: Hmmm...advice on Enderman-proofing your house from someone called *Ender* is not suspicious at all...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not aware of any there being any "infrastructure targeting" code in Minecraft.

The situations you describe however, seem to have three possible explanations:

1. **The random number generator hates you.** This is a known phenomenon dating all the way back to early dice games. Simply put, the random number generator appears to actively work to destroy you.  Short of making a shrine to the RNG gods, no solution to this problem is known.
2. **Selective memory.** You are simply remembering the times you were horribly griefed more vividly than the times mobs spawned out in the open where you could easily take them on, even if they are equally common.
3. **Death from above.** The first two situations you gave sound like you were in an enclosed, partially lit cave. This type of environment would increase the spawn chance in other nearby areas. In such a scenario, mobs using "Death from Above" tactics is for more likely, especially in abandoned mine-shafts. The Enderman case you describe just sounds like bad luck (See point 1).

Comment: +1 for mentioning selective memory! Also, there is code that makes Creeper's fuse shorter when they are above a player, so they are indeed trained in combat drops.

Comment: Why hasn't this been chosen as the answer yet?

Comment: Asker is probably AFK.

Comment: Creepers are devious creatures anyway. I'm pretty sure they're programmed to hide around corners and yell *SSSSSURPRISE!*

Comment: Nope, just drop from above.

Comment: Adding to 2 there are many times when mobs spawn and you never encounter them.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such code, it's completely random.

It looks like the "troll-engine" is playing with you (or maybe it's Herobrine's work... nobody knows).

Comment: I think Herobrine was [removed in some version](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Herobrine#Changelogs).

Comment: he has never been in minecraft. they say he has be removed in every update, its like a tradition.

Comment: I know ... I even linked to the wiki article explaining that ... maybe I should have left that smiley face in that comment ;-)

Comment: its fun im always like: "what the heck, have i played minecraft with him running around?????" ;D

Comment: @RustyMembers Yes. He has been following you around. Watching you from behind trees. Standing over you while you sleep, feeding on your dreams.

Comment: don't make my cry...... IMMA ****** **** ** *** ****  ******* KILL HIM!